# NJsonSchema C# code generation creates generic objects instead of classes

Tags: c#, json, schema, code-generation, jsonschema

I am having trouble understanding NJsonSchema's take on the following schema and the classes generated. I cannot change the schema as this is defined by someone else. The schema posted below is simplified to demonstrate the problem ([link to the entire schema](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9lrzkog5b8bicn/EnergyPlus_22_2_0.schema.json?dl=0)). I would like to create a set of C# classes that can output a valid file following the schema. However, the NJsonSchema code generator just fills in generic objects and does not populate the fields and properties described by the schema.

**The generator code:**

```
    var schema = JsonSchema.FromFileAsync(@"../../../SchemaSnippets.json");
    CSharpGeneratorSettings set = new CSharpGeneratorSettings();
    set.Namespace = "EPJSON";
    set.SchemaType = SchemaType.JsonSchema;
    set.GenerateDataAnnotations = true;
    set.AnyType = "object";
    set.ClassStyle = CSharpClassStyle.Poco;
    set.HandleReferences = false;
    var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema.Result, set);
    var file = generator.GenerateFile();
    File.WriteAllText(@"../../../SchemaSnippetsCode.cs", file);
```

**The Schema:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "Version": {
      "patternProperties": {
        ".*": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "version_identifier": {
              "type": "string",
              "default": "22.2"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "group": "Simulation Parameters",
      "legacy_idd": {
        "field_info": {
          "version_identifier": {
            "field_name": "Version Identifier",
            "field_type": "a"
          }
        },
        "fields": [
          "version_identifier"
        ],
        "alphas": {
          "fields": [
            "version_identifier"
          ]
        },
        "numerics": {
          "fields": []
        }
      },
      "type": "object",
      "maxProperties": 1,
      "memo": "Specifies the EnergyPlus version of the IDF file.",
      "format": "singleLine"
    }
  }
}
```

**The generated class output looks like this:**

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.8.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)")]
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Version", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> Version { get; set; }
        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
    public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
    {
        get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
        set { _additionalProperties = value; }
    }
```

**I was expecting/hoping for something along these lines:**

```
    public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, VersionObject> Version { get; set; }

    class VersionObject
    {
        string version_identifier { get; set; } = "22.2";
    }
```

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Robert. The website does not seem to support schemas. It crashes when I give it the full schema. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9lrzkog5b8bicn/EnergyPlus_22_2_0.schema.json?dl=0